# PHP str_replace not working correctly

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I'm using str_replace and it's not working correctly.
I have a text area, which input is sent with a form. When the data is received by the server, I want to change the new lines to ",".

```
$teams = $_GET["teams"];
$teams = str_replace("\n",",",$teams);
echo $teams;
```

Strangely, I receive the following result

Chelsea

,real

,Barcelona

instead of Chealsea,real,Barcelona.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand on Waage's response, you could use an array to replace both sets of characters

```
$teams = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"),",",$teams);
echo $teams;
```

This should handle both items properly, as a single `\n` is valid and would not get caught if you were just replacing `\r\n`

Comment: `trim()` only removes whitespace characters from the beginning and end of a string, not in the middle.

Comment: Yea, it dawned on me he wasn't doing it to the end of the string :) Modified to be a better response!

Comment: A little bit lost now, what's the difference between the two answers?

Comment: Nothing really, mine just shows the code to convert `\r\n` AND `\n` to a ",". I think waage was hinting to this, I just showed the code to accomplish it.

Comment: Ah, the old carriage return/line feed troubles. You'd think in 2016 we'd be past this by now...

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing `"\r\n"` instead of just `"\n"`

Answer (score 4):

I would trim the text and replace all consecutive CR/LF characters with a comma:

```
$text = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', ',', trim($text))
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but found a different answer so thought I would share in case it helps someone.

The problem I had was that I wanted to replace `\n` with `<br/>` for printing in HTML. The simple change I had to make was to escape the backslash in `str_replace("\n","<br>",($text))` like this:

```
str_replace("\\n","<br>",($text))
```