# Can not delete new line

Tags: php, newline

There is a user textarea input. I need to remove all new lines before saving (so it should be only one line).

I use

```
$text = str_replace("\r\n", "", $text);
$text = str_replace("\n", "", $text);
```

for this.

But one user entered text, that has new line, and it cannot be removed with that code.
I also tried `\r\n` and `\r` with no result.

I cannot copy it here, because as soon as I copy it, new line will be replaced with standard `\n`.

How can I remove this new line? Or how can I see what its character is?
It is saved in MySQL now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reliably Remove Newlines From String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274506/reliably-remove-newlines-from-string)

Comment: No, it is not duplicate. I did not find answer there.

Comment: ok, if that's not a duplicate, then how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449580/replacing-r-n-with-php or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654844/php-str-replace-not-working-correctly or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779464/php-simple-way-to-replace-or-remove-empty-lines-with-str-replace or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057405/newline-question. And if you still insist that it's not a duplicate you should update your question to point out why it's not a duplicate of any of those because I have a hard time seeing any difference between your question and those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

- RTRIM http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php : rtrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string
- TRIM http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php :  trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

**After clarification**

```
// Order of replacement
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '';

// Processes \r\n's first so they aren't converted twice.
$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);
```

This is direct from the PHP manual:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Code from manual also does not work. Is is the same as mine, just using arrays. New line is still here. All others new lines works ok.

Comment: how are you validating that the "new line is still here" ?

Comment: I see it here when it is loaded in the textarea. Also can see it in phpMyAdmin. There are all inputs from one user. May be he has some special OS.

Comment: If you are unable to replicate the problem yourself ... by using a string with `\r\n` etc. i'd be inclined to think your code works and it's something else... maybe ^M ;)